# What different between Teamviewer Full editon and Teamviewer Host edition?

Tags: teamviewer

As i known, the full edition is server+viewer function, host edition only server function?
But how about the capability  of server function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeamViewer Host gets installed on e.g. a Server as a service, and you can connect to it from remote anytime you need. Normal teamviewer full edition connects people by "running" the teamviewer software themselves (having to run them manually each time), or to connect to TeamViewer Host servers.

Have a look here, which describes the editions:
http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to have both of them installed, TV Host from your internal IT department and as a service, and in parallel TV Full for just connecting to other computers with license, users starts the application

Comment: @HrvojeKusulja I think this works, yes

Comment: I have checked, it is not supported, by offical docs..